# array_replace_recursive() without creation of keys

Tags: php

In PHP, `array_replace_recursive()` does two things according to the documentation:

- If a key from the first array exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value from the second array.
- If the key exists in the second array, and not the first, it will be created in the first array.

Is there an alternative that *only* does the replacement, and doesn't create new keys?

For example:

```php
$array = [
  'apple' => TRUE,
  'pear' => TRUE,
  'basket' => [
    'banana' => TRUE,
  ],
  'punnet' => [
    'strawberry' => TRUE,
  ],
];

$replacement = [
  'banana' => [
    'REPLACEMENT!'
  ],
];
```

The result should be:

```php
$array = [
  'apple' => TRUE,
  'pear' => TRUE,
  'basket' => [
    'banana' => [
      'REPLACEMENT!'
    ],
  ],
  'punnet' => [
    'strawberry' => TRUE,
  ],
];
```

Comment: Could you show a specific example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You have misunderstood array_replace_recursive().

Comment: array_replace_recursive() doesn't do what I need. That's not the same as not understanding it. Also, I'd argue that what array_replace_recursive() does is not 'replace'.

Comment: @joachim Nope, it does what it says. Keys need to match between the first array and second array for replacement. See this link to understand the difference between your replacement and the one in the link. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f2c106bfc440c69da49484a45985f63c0a9e3ba4

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `array_intersect_key()` to create an array that contains only the keys that are in the two arrays, then you can merge.

```
$array1 = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
    'd' => 4,
];

$array2 = [
    'b' => 14,
    'c' => 70,
    'f' => 5,
];

// $array2 has to be the first arguments for $inter to have its value instead of the value of $array1
$inter = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);

$merged = array_replace_recursive($array1, $inter);

// Merged will be: 
[
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 14,
    'c' => 70,
    'd' => 4,
];
```

- [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

*EDIT*
For this to work recursively, you can use this function found [here](http://arstropica.com/uncategorized/php-recursive-array-intersect-key/)

```
/** 
* Recursively computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison.
* 
* @param   array $array1 The array with master keys to check.
* @param   array $array2 An array to compare keys against.
* @return  array associative array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in array2.
**/
function array_intersect_key_recursive(array $array1, array $array2) {
    $array1 = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);

    foreach ($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        if (is_array($value) && is_array($array2[$key])) {
            $value = array_intersect_key_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array1;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be recursive, not just the first layer.

Comment: Ok. PHP does not have that directly. We need to implemented it. Hopefully it has already been done. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure intersection is the right thing to do here. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: The haystack has `banana` is inside `basket`; the needle has `banana` on the first level -- neither of these snippets will work as required.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I needed:

```php
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value, $key, $replacements) {
  if (isset($replacements[$key])) {
    $value = $replacements[$key];
  }
}, ['replace' => 'replacement']);
```

Comment: This unexplained answer works with the sample data because the sought value/replacement is on a leaf-node.